# Birth-death process with fixed lifespan

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, law-of-large-numbers, birth-death-process

Consider a continuous time stochastic process where an individual is born at each tick of a poisson clock which has rate $n$. Each individual has a fixed life span of a unit of time. Let there be 0 individuals, initially. Does the process return to the 0 individuals state with probability 1? Is the mean time of returning to the 0 state finite?

PS. I need this result to establish the convergence of the average (over time) of a queue length in a (non-markovian) queue with abandonments (individuals abandon if not served after a unit of time)

Comment: Is $n$ fixed or does it vary with time?

Comment: @Math1000 n is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the birth of individuals is a Poisson process with rate $n$, then looking and the previous unit of time that ends at this instant, the number of births $b$ follows the following probability distribution:
$$
P(b) = e^{-n} \frac{n^b}{b!}
$$

The probability of having $0$ individuals at a given instant is given by
$$
P(0) = e^{-n}
$$
(since $n^0 = 1$ and $0! = 1$).

Assuming that $n$ is finite, eventually we will have $0$ individuals, on average after $1/P(0) = e^n$ units of time.

---

By the way, if you are thinking about taking care of the individuals, you should be able to do it at a rate higher than $n$ individuals per unit of time. For instance:

If, on average, we get $n=10$ births per unit of time and we can deal with, on average, $m=10$ individuals per unit of time, we will have individuals dying if the number of births $b > 10$, i.e., $b \geq 11$, that happens with a probability near $40\%$:
$$ \begin{array}{cc}
\hline
j & P(b \geq j) \\
\hline
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0.99995 \\
2 & 0.9995 \\
3 & 0.997 \\
4 & 0.990 \\
5 & 0.971 \\
6 & 0.933 \\
7 & 0.870 \\
8 & 0.780 \\
9 & 0.667 \\
10 & 0.542 \\
11 & 0.417 \\
12 & 0.303 \\
13 & 0.208 \\
14 & 0.136 \\
15 & 0.0835 \\
16 & 0.0487 \\
17 & 0.0270 \\
18 & 0.0143 \\
19 & 0.00719 \\
20 & 0.00345 \\
\hline \\
\end{array}
$$

Using the Normal approximation to the Poisson distribution, we should have around $97.73\%$ of the events up to $n + 2 \sqrt{n}$, in the above example it means that $b > 10 + 2 \times \sqrt{10} = 16.3$; and we should have around $99.87\%$ of the events up to $n + 3 \sqrt{n}$, meaning that $b > 19.5$

Comment: Thanks a lot... I was thinking about approximating the stochastic process with its discrete skeleton to make it a finite space markov chain, but the solution turns out to be embarrassingly simlpe : )

Comment: A quick follow up question: the fact that we eventually return to state 0, with probability 1 in finite time, suffices for the time average of the number of individuals to converge, correct? That is, $1/T * \int_{t=0}^T B(t) dt$ converges, where B(t) is the number of individuals alive at time t.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'm not sure about that last question, may I suggest that you post a new question on the site?